# Using v-for to show dynamic slides in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, v-for

Having some trouble with a custom Vue component using Vue Carousel(https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/) to build a slide from a node list in the index file. Some of the carousel data is read in through a `data.json` file, but I want to create a new slide based on an object containing a node list. So I believe I need to us v-for and then iterate through that object creating a `<slide></slide>` for each instance in the node list.

The NodeList is made in the mounted() lifehook, but Im not sure how to tie it to the component, ALSO still very new to Vue and I didn't build out this templating system. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
import { Carousel, Slide } from 'vue-carousel';
let articles={};

export default {
    name: 'ProductCarousel',
    props: {
      dnode: Object,
      value: Object
    },
    components: { 
        Carousel,
        Slide    
    },
    data() {
      return {
        carousel: this.dnode,
        product: articles
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      var _self = this;
      var rowName = ".js-ep--" + _self.carousel.anchor;
      let e4pRow = document.querySelector(rowName);
      var productRows;

      if (e4pRow && !window.isEditMode) {
        productRows = e4pRow.querySelectorAll(".product-grid");
  
        if (productRows) {
          for (var len = productRows.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            articles[i] = productRows[i].querySelectorAll("article");
            //console.log(articles[i]);
          }
        //console.log(articles);
        }
      }
    }
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template>
<section :id="carousel.anchor" :class="carousel.classList" >
  
    <h1 v-if="carousel.header" v-text="carousel.header" />
    <h2 v-if="carousel.subheader" v-text="carousel.subheader"/>
    <p v-if="carousel.paragraphText" v-text="carousel.paragraphText" />
    <carousel 
    :navigationEnabled="carousel.navigation"
    :paginationEnabled="carousel.pagination"
    :navigationNextLabel="carousel.navigationNextIcon"
    :navigationPrevLabel="carousel.navigationPrevIcon"
    :navigationClickTargetSize="carousel.arrowClickSize"
    :perPageCustom="[
    [640, carousel.numSlidesSmall], 
    [1024, carousel.numSlidesMedium],
    [1920, carousel.numSlidesLarge]]">
        <slide></slide>
    </carousel>
  </section>
</template>
```

Comment: Every variable you can use in the template must belong to the Vue instance. To add variables to the Vue instance you must first declare them as properties of your data object, then assign values to them using the `this.yourVariable` syntax.

Comment: oh thank you! I will try that out! Excuse my brevity, first post about Vue and actually in Stackoverflow... @Ayrton 

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Carousel, Slide } from 'vue-carousel';
let articles={};

export default {
    name: 'ProductCarousel',
    props: {
      dnode: Object,
      value: Object
    },
    components: { 
        Carousel,
        Slide    
    },
    data() {
      return {
        carousel: this.dnode,
        product: []
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      var _self = this;
      var rowName = ".js-ep--" + _self.carousel.anchor;
      let e4pRow = document.querySelector(rowName);
      var productRows;

      if (e4pRow && !window.isEditMode) {
        productRows = e4pRow.querySelectorAll(".product-grid");

        if (productRows) {
          for (var len = productRows.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            articles[i] = productRows[i].querySelectorAll("article");
            //console.log(articles[i]);
          }
        //console.log(articles);
          this.product = articles; //loop through product in your template
        }
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried using something like thist: `<slide v-bind="{value}" v-for="value in products" :key="value.id">
        </slide>` but that is not creating the slides based on the Nodelist captured not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: I think I am using the life cycle hooks in correctly. Maybe need to use render function before mounted? Found [this guide](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/)